Java Script for an internet HTML and JS speed test wrong structure
I am trying to get this script to work, but when I click the check button, it doesn't do anything, there is something wrong with the script, probably in the while cycle. The idea is to download the same image 10 times and average the resulted download speed.
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var imageLink = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Tokyo_Sky_Tree_2012.JPG',
    downloadSize = 8185374,
    time_start, time_end,
    downloadSrc = new Image();
    document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('.loader').classList.remove('hide');
    
    var j= 0;
    var FInalSpeed;
    
    while (j<10) {
      time_start = new Date().getTime();
      console.log(time_start
      var cacheImg = "?nn=" + time_start;
      downloadSrc.src = imageLink + cacheImg;
      console.log(downloadSrc);
      downloadSrc.onload = function() {
        //this function will trigger once the image loads
        time_end = new Date().getTime();
        var timeDuration = (time_end - time_start) / 1000;
        loadedBytes = downloadSize * 8,
        totalSpeed = ((loadedBytes / timeDuration) / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
        FinalSpeed= FinalSpeed + totalSpeed;
    
        let i=0, speedOut;
        const animate = () => {
          if ( i < FinalSpeed ) {
            document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = i.toFixed(2) + '<small>Mbps</small>';
            setTimeout(animate, 20);
            i+=1.02;
          } else {
            document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = FinalSpeed + '<small>Mbps</small>';
          }
        }
        animate();

        document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = FinalSpeed + '<small>Mbps</small>';
        document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.remove('hide');
        document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.add('result');
        document.querySelector('.loader').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.content').classList.remove('hide');
        e.target.innerText = 'CHECK AGAIN';
    }
})

I tried changing the cycle, declaring the vars, not declaring the vars. But I can't find where the issue is comming from, it seems to be a basic structure problem.

There no language named java script there is java or javascript. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

The script never changes the value of j so it's an infinite loop.

your braces are mismatched

I doubt that using slow JS functions and small images is a reliable internet speed indication. Theres more to it such as traffic, packages, package losses... A decent start would be to look into asynchronous scripting, making usage of web-workers and looking for efficiency within your code. then loading packages from a dedicated server and not a public Wikipedia server where the connection to the server will be a bottleneck not the users internet.

"I tried changing the cycle, declaring the vars, not declaring the vars. But I can't find where the issue is comming from, it seems to be a basic structure problem" ... You speak of it as if it isnt your code. Where did you get it from? Aside from the numerous problems as mentioned in above comments, your misunderstanding of what the onload event does for the sole instantiation of image in your (infinite) loop is evident.

On a sidenote: your code seems a bit messy, maybe you could use some sort of linter (e.g. eslint) or code prettifier (e.g. prettier)? That makes it much easier to trace errors in your code and improves your developer experience.
One small example: you define a variable FInalSpeed (uppercase i), but then use a variable named FinalSpeed (lowercase i) later in the code. This is not exactly a problem in Javascript, but still adds to the messy looks of your code.

@Rico Good catch on the variable mismatch naming (FInalSpeed) but it is most definitely a problem as javascript is case sensitive on identifiers.

Of course you are right @GetSet .. to better explain my comment: the explicit definition of a variable in Javascript is not mandatory (you could just use it without definition) and the following code should still work without the variable being set. However, in this situation it indeed causes a part of the problem because the variable isn't defined globally but only local to the onload-handler ..

Using the JS script is the best way to test the internet connection for the users, if you are speaking about testing the sync speed comming to your house as once upon a time, they were aiming to bring the same speed to all devices, thats done through the router or with a cable on the back of the router while disconnecting all other devices, in most cases people say my speed is not what the ISP says, but it is, its just not known its the speed comming to the router, not the WiFi.

there are a lot of things going bad here, i'll tel you what i recommend doing,

you should use async in this case to use await inside
set finalSpeed to 0 strong text(just in case undefined actions...)
change from while to for, again to use async/await.
add a promise to await for that image :)
better speed download tracking
and handling errors (very important) ;)
also i avarage the speed of the dawnload

the code should look like this:
// Changed to an async function to use await inside
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    const imageLink = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Tokyo_Sky_Tree_2012.JPG';
    const downloadSize = 8185374;
    let FinalSpeed = 0; // Initialized FinalSpeed to 0 to fix undefined addition issue

    document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('.loader').classList.remove('hide');

    // Changed while loop to for loop to use async/await for sequential downloads
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        const time_start = new Date().getTime();
        const cacheImg = "?nn=" + time_start;
        const downloadSrc = new Image();

        // Wrapped the onload event in a promise to await image loading
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            downloadSrc.onload = function() {
                const time_end = new Date().getTime();
                const timeDuration = (time_end - time_start) / 1000;
                const loadedBytes = downloadSize * 8;
                const totalSpeed = (loadedBytes / timeDuration) / 1024 / 1024;
                FinalSpeed += totalSpeed; // Accumulates speed for each download
                resolve(); // Resolve the promise once the image has loaded
            };
            downloadSrc.onerror = reject; // Handle image load errors
            downloadSrc.src = imageLink + cacheImg;
        });
        }
    
        FinalSpeed = (FinalSpeed / 10).toFixed(2); // Averages the speed after all downloads

        document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = FinalSpeed + '<small>Mbps</small>';
        document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.remove('hide');
        document.querySelector('.loader-content').classList.add('result');
        document.querySelector('.loader').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.content').classList.remove('hide');
        e.target.innerText = 'CHECK AGAIN'; // Ready for a new check
    });

Test it and tell me if it fixed the errors you've got,
also JavaScript has no spaces on the name :p

Nicely done (provided it works). Could you turn this into a runnable snippet here?

Thanks! I am a beginner in JS, I am sorry for the incorrect process. My idea was to make a good HTML speedtest, I took a ready example and reworked it, but had some problems. After testing it, I found out its best to set the cycle value to 5 instead of 8, for weaker connections, but it may be better to set it to higher for better connections. I think the measurement will be inaccurate for faster speeds. You can use this to check it if you want cc.free.bg

I added a little bit of a test for slow speed connections:
if (FinalSpeed/j < 5 && j==5)
j = 0;

@GetSet , maybe yes, I'll take a look on that of course
